# React delaying render while fetch call populates Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render

Is there a way to delay Reacts render while making a fetch call to populate a Redux store so that when the render calls this.props from the store the data is already there? I have an issue where the store call in the render method is calling the store which is currently an empty object and it causes the render to crash.

So far the solution I came up with was to make an empty JSON with null data that the render first calls then when the fetch succeeds it calls the now populated Redux store, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: In the first place, the  default structure has  to be in your reducer, then, in your render, you can test `this.props.stuff && <AComponent />` and  thus you ll avoid  crushing and your component will render this part only if there is valid values

Comment: Take a look at this article : https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-redux/
In particular the productReducer.js code where he sets loading true/false

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to delay any renders this is a part or react functionality.

It renders as it gets new data (props, state).

In your case, you need to address different "data situations"

So first your reducer should have a default state, ie:

```
{
  "loading": false,
  "username": null,
  "isLoaded": false
}
```

now in your code you can address the different data and render diff views accordingly

```
const YourComponent = props => {
  if (props.loading) {
    return <h1>loading</h1>
  }
  if (props.loaded && props.username==null) {
    return <h1>cant find user</h1>
  }
  return <h1>{props.username} is loaded</h1>
}
```

this is just an example your code should be nicer and more organized :)